# Solution for Phol's pendulum (forced and dampened harmonic oscillator)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

The equation of motion for the forced and dampened harmonic oscillator for Phol's pendulum is the following:

$$I_{zz}\ddot{\phi}+b\dot{\phi}+k\phi=M_0\cos{(\omega t +\phi_0)}$$ or $$\ddot{\phi} + \frac{b}{I_{zz}}\dot{\phi}+\frac{k}{I_{zz}}\phi=\frac{M_0}{I_{zz}}\cos{(\omega t +\phi_0)}.$$

Here, taking $\gamma:=\frac{b}{2I_{zz}}$ and $\omega_0:=\sqrt{\frac{k}{I_{zz}}}$, we get the following final expression

$$\ddot{\phi} + 2\gamma\dot{\phi}+\omega_0^2\phi=\frac{M_0}{I_{zz}}\cos{(\omega t +\phi_0)}.$$

Solving the homogeneous equation with the boundary condition of $\dot{\phi}(0)=0$, I get the equation:

$$\phi(t)=Ce^{-\gamma t}\cos{(\omega_\gamma t + \delta)}$$ where $$\omega_\gamma := \sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}.$$

Now is where I don't know how to continue. I should get the particular solution for the full ODE and then add both solutions together. To do this, I'd try with an expression of the form $A\cos{(\omega t + \phi_0)}$ and then by substituting in the ODE I'd solve for $A$. However, I've seen the solution and it's of the form $A=\cos{(\omega t + \phi_0 + \lambda)}$ and I don't know where the $\lambda $ comes from.

I'd like someone to guide me through the process of getting the particular solution by giving some advice on how I should approach the problem.

Comment: Use this Ansatz $~\phi (t)=A\,e^{i\left( \omega t+\phi _{0}\right) }$

Comment: @Eli And how would that get me the extra term $\lambda$ in the cosine